# Spring Boot Starter Cache - Velocity is missing?

Tags: java, spring, maven

i am testing **Spring Boot 1.3.0.M3** with **ehcache** and got some problems.

When i'm starting the application following exception occurs on the console:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'velocityConfigurer' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/velocity/VelocityAutoConfiguration$VelocityWebConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/CommonsLogLogChute    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:971)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:960)
>     at
>   com.aconso.creator2.CreatorApplication.main(CreatorApplication.java:26)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/CommonsLogLogChute    at
>   org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory.createVelocityEngine(VelocityEngineFactory.java:238)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(VelocityConfigurer.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 20 more

My pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M3</version>
</parent>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

mvn depency:tree

> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile [INFO] |  | 
>   +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  -
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.1.Final:compile [INFO] |  | 
>   +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile [INFO] |  |     - com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.1:compile [INFO] |
>   |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.1:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  -
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.1:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |  -
>   org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |
>   - org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.0.M3:provided
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:provided [INFO] |
>   +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:compile [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:provided
>   [INFO] |  -
>   org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:provided
>   [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] | 
>   -
>   org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  -
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.3.3:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile [INFO] |  | 
>   +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile [INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile [INFO] |  |     |  |  +-
>   org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile [INFO] |  |     |  |  +-
>   joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile [INFO] |  |     |  |  +-
>   org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile [INFO] |  |     |  | 
>   +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.4:compile [INFO] |  |     |  |  +- ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:compile [INFO] |  |     |  |  - net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile [INFO] |  |     | 
>   +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile [INFO] |  |     |  - commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile [INFO] |  |
>   +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile [INFO] |  |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile [INFO] |  |     +-
>   velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile [INFO] |  |     +-
>   org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0GA:compile [INFO] |  |     +-
>   xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile [INFO] |  |     +-
>   xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime [INFO] |  |     +-
>   xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime [INFO] |  |     -
>   xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime [INFO] |  |        -
>   xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] | 
>   - org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  -
>   nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.2.9:compile
>   [INFO] +-
>   org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile [INFO]
>   |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile [INFO] |  |  +-
>   org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile [INFO] |  |  -
>   org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |  -
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.3:compile [INFO]
>   |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.3:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile [INFO] |  -
>   org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  -
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.6:compile [INFO] |  | 
>   - org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.6:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.0.M3:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.23:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  |  - org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  -
>   org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile [INFO]
>   |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile [INFO] |
>   |  +-
>   org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile [INFO] |  |  |  -
>   org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile [INFO] |  |  +-
>   dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile [INFO] |  |  +-
>   org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  -
>   org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.0.RC1:compile [INFO]
>   |  |  +-
>   org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.0.RC1:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +-
>   org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |  | 
>   - org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO] | 
>   - org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile [INFO]
>   +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:runtime [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.3.0.M3:test
>   [INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test [INFO] |  +-
>   org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test [INFO] |  |  -
>   org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test [INFO] |  +-
>   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test [INFO] |  +-
>   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test [INFO] |  -
>   org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:test [INFO] +-
>   org.webjars:angularjs:jar:1.4.2:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.webjars:jquery:jar:2.1.4:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:3.3.5:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.webjars:angular-file-upload:jar:5.0.0:compile [INFO] +-
>   net.sf.jtidy:jtidy:jar:r938:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.2:compile [INFO] -
>   net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.0:compile

I have an ehcache.xml in my classpath and the EHCacheManager is instantiated.
When i remove the spring-boot-starter-cache- and ehcache-dependency everything starts fine. (But then only with ConcurrentMapCacheManager)

**Question:**

Do I need velocity with spring-boot-starter-cache or is there something other missing or wrong?

Comment: It seems that CommonsLogLogChute is not in your classPath. :"nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/CommonsLogLogChute"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `VelocityAutoConfiguration` only kicks in if these 2 classes are present in the classpath:

```
@ConditionalOnClass({ VelocityEngine.class, VelocityEngineFactory.class })
```

They come from `org.apache.velocity:velocity` and `org.springframework:spring-context-support` respectively.

You can identify which dependencies are transitively adding those to the project with:

`mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Do i need velocity for using spring-starter-cache and ehcache? When it is needed, why spring-data-cache do not have it as a dependency? I'm using thymeleaf as template engine and do not need velocity too.

Comment: Ok, org.springframework:spring-context-support is in my dependencies. It comes from org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache. But i do not find org.apache.velocity:velocity in my dependency tree.

Comment: maybe it's with a slightly different name, try `mvn dependency:tree | grep velocity`

Comment: Ah ok. I edited my post and add the dependency:tree. It seems that spring-security-cas has a dependency to velocity:velocity:jar. My solution is now that i add the spring-boot-starter-velocity dependency and disable it in application.properties via spring.velocity.enabled=false. After that it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with spring-security-cas depending on velocity. You can solve the problem by adding

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = VelocityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

to your spring boot application main class

Answer (score 0):

With the latest versions of Spring Boot, you can do this -

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = VelocityAutoConfiguration.class)
```